# LiveChart Winform Geared crashes in Cartesian chart for Column series

Tags: .net, winforms, livecharts

I am evaluating the Winform livechart.Geared because our customers might have about 20K+ data points.
I am doing the cartesian chart for Column series.

From my understanding, all my livechart-related code should be the same except changing the ChartValues to GearedValues. However when I did that, my app will display the column series for a brief moment but then it will crash. And I only use 50 data points just for testing.

And this is the message from the exception:
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

```
            cartesianChart1.Series.Clear();

            cartesianChart1.Series.Add(
               new ColumnSeries
               {
                   Title = "Employees",
                   DataLabels = true,
                   Values = new GearedValues<int>(totalEmployeesList)
               }
            );

            cartesianChart1.Series.Add(
                new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Title = "Strangers",
                    DataLabels = true,
                    Values = new GearedValues<int>(totalNonemployeesList)
                }
            );
```

This works fine with ChartValues but not with GearedValues.

Thank you very much.

Comment: From my experience with LiveCharts you simply cant do it with 20k points. Take a look at Oxyplot or SkiaSharp Oxyplot (for better performance)

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the late reply. Somehow I never got a notification when my post got replied. I was able to solve it without using the GearedValues.
And thank you for the other recommendations!